# JAX-RS CXF access HTTP body from @BeanParam

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf

My question is simple, but I didn't manage to find a response... Is it possible with JAX-RS (using CXF implementation) to access the HTTP request body from a @BeanParam annotated parameter ?

I tried this but **it doesn't work** :

```
@Path("/courses")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CarsResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Course update(@BeanParam CarUpdateRequest request){
        ...
    }
}

 public class CarUpdateRequest {
     @PathParam("id")
     private String id;
     private CarUpdateData data; // inject here the body using JsonProvider
 }
```

It seems like an helloword example but I can't find any working example. It's strange that JAX-RS doesn't have a @BodyParam...

Comment: It's not going to work like that. You just need to put the `CarUpdateData` as a method parameter

Comment: Yes that's what I thought... Still I think it's a pity that the BeanParam doesn't offer the possibility of accessing the body like with any other @*Param.